# Java SimpleDateFormat Wrong Timezone after parsing

Tags: java, date, timezone

Why: When I give input date string with GMT timezone, `SimpleDateFormat` parses it and outputs EET timezone?

```java
public static String DATE_FORMAT="dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z";
public static String CURRENT_DATE_STRING ="31 October 2011 11:19:56 GMT";
...
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parseObject(CURRENT_DATE_STRING));
```

And the output is:

> Mon Oct 31 13:19:56 EET 2011

rather than

> Mon Oct 31 13:19:56 GMT 2011

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're printing out the result of `Date.toString()`. A `Date` doesn't have any concept of a timezone - it's just the number of milliseconds since the UTC Unix epoch. `Date.toString()` *always* uses the system default time zone.

Note that you shouldn't be expecting "Mon Oct 31 13:19:56 GMT 2011" given that you've given a time which specifies a GMT hour of 11, not 13.

If you want to use a specific time zone for printing, you should use another `DateFormat` for the printing, rather than using `Date.toString()`. (`Date.toString()` keeps causing confusion like this; it's really unfortunate.)

Answer (score 0):

### `java.util.Date` does not hold timezone information.

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents the number of ***milliseconds*** since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (or UTC). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and **timezone**, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable **timezone**.

Apart from this, there are a couple of problems with your code:

1. Use `H` instead of `h` for the 24-Hour format. The letter, `h` is used for the 12-Hour format (i.e. with AM/PM marker).
2. Even though `MMM` works for parsing the long name of the month (e.g. January) with `SimpleDateFormat`, it is meant for the 3-letter month name (e.g. Jan). If you try doing it with the modern Date-Time API, you will be greeted with the [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html). You should use `MMMM` for the long name of the month.

**Demo incorporating these points:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "31 October 2011 11:19:56 GMT";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);

        String strDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);

        // Some other format
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        strDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);

        // The last format with some other timezone
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        strDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
31 October 2011 11:19:56 GMT
October 31 11:19:56 GMT 2011
October 31 07:19:56 EDT 2011
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/s0nH99)

### Switch to `java.time` API.

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "31 October 2011 11:19:56 GMT";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM uuuu HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Some other format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfAnother = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDate = dtfAnother.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-10-31T11:19:56Z[GMT]
October 31 11:19:56 GMT 2011
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/uieg2D)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>