# wrong time calculating in Java

Tags: java, date, sum

when I want to sum two dates in java it does not work:

```
System.out.println(date + " <---- date");
System.out.println(time + " <---- time");
System.out.println(new Date(date.getTime() + time.getTime()) + " <---- new Date(time.getTime() + date.getTime())");
```

leads to following output:

```
Wed Nov 06 00:00:00 CET 2013 <---- date
Thu Jan 01 11:51:14 CET 1970 <---- time
Wed Nov 06 10:51:14 CET 2013 <---- new Date(time.getTime() + date.getTime())
```

... but if i work with `Calender` it works!

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTime(time);
  int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

  calendar.setTime(date);
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

  Date myDate = calendar.getTime();
  System.out.println(myDate);
```

results in

```
Wed Nov 06 11:51:00 CET 2013
```

which is correct

Can anybody explain me why?

Comment: This post might be able to help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2126252/2915099)

Comment: [java.util.Date does not hold timezone information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414757/10819573).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, you've got problems with time zones here. The fact that you're using a `java.util.Date` to represent a time of day is messing you up to start with. Your time of 11:51:14 CET is actually 10:51:14 UTC, so when you add the result of calling `time.getTime()`, you're only adding "just under 11 hours" rather than "just under 12 hours". The use of inappropriate data types makes all this hard to work with and understand.

I'd *strongly* recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) for all of this. Then you can start with a `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`, combine them into a `LocalDateTime` and then work out if you want to apply a particular time zone.

Using the right data types, which mean exactly what you're trying to convey, makes a *huge* difference for date/time work.